# Joomla user registration insert file

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am looking for file in joomla 3, where is the query that inputs into db values from registration fields?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `com_users`?

Comment: Yeah, but I can not find specific query.

Comment: There is no specific query. I believe the registration process is done through the core library, however you **can** extend it if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the code from `com_users` you will see that it loads and uses the Model `UsersModelUser` (loaded from */administrator/models/user.php* ) which in turn uses the class `JUser` (loaded from */libraries/joomla/user/user.php* ).

If you want to create/alter users, you should load and instance of `UsersModelUser` and use it's `load()` to load an existing user and it's `save()` method to store any change or to create new user entries.

By using the `UsersModelUser`  and therefore `JUser` you will get all of the niceties like two-factor authentication (if it's configured) and the correct hash for the password based on the authentication system/plugins in use. It will even generate a random password if you don't pass one in the with data used to create a new user.

Comment: Nicely explained. Thanks.